# Getting image from url located in JSON

Tags: css, angular, image, typescript

I need to extract the url and to show it as a pictures:

How it looks from json:

[image: how it looks from json]

My html:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let product of store.Products">

    <p>Product ProductImage: {{ product.ProductImage }}</p>
    <p>Product Price: {{ product.Price }}</p>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Can I do it with pipe?

Comment: aren't you supposed to use the **<img>** tag to show it as an image ? write it as `<img src={{product.ProductImage}}>`

Comment: It didn't work with it. but know I did like you say and its fine thanks!!

Comment: [Refer to this article for iterating img](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40797925/how-to-bind-img-src-in-angular-2-in-ngfor) using ngFor. In my experience it should work because I have tested it.

Answer (score 1):

i see a space in the json you provided, you need

```
<p>Product ProductImage: {{ product["Product ProductImage"] }}</p>
<p>Product Price: {{ product.Price }}</p>
```

you need to replace with image tag if you want to see an image

```
  <p><img [src]="product["Product ProductImage"]" /></p>
  <p>Product Price: {{ product.Price }}</p>
```

Comment: thanks. I am not sure I understand (the syntex of  {{ product["Product ProductImage"] }})

Comment: since you have a space between Product and ProductImage, you need to use [""] instead of dot operator

Comment: Am I missing something? Thank you   <p><img [src]="product["Product ProductImage"]"/></p>

Comment: try this <img src="{{product["Product ProductImage"]}}></img>

Comment: can you post the json that you are getting?