# Send too many request to server when need to get image with image

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to get image from server in Angular 7 with blob.
I  wrote this service for send request:

```
  downloadImage(id: number): Observable<any> {
    console.log('in service ')
    return this.http.request('GET', this.appConfig.apiEndpoint + '/Post/DownloadFileForManager/' + id, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
  }
```

My Typescript code:

```
DownloadImage(id: number): Observable<any> {
this.postService.downloadImage(id).subscribe(data => {
  const arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(data);
  const blob = new Blob([arrayBufferView], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
  const urlCreator = window.URL;
  const imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
  this.image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imageUrl);
})
return this.image;
}
```

This is my HTML code:

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="thumbnail">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ 'GENERAL.PHOTO' | translate }} </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <img class="table-user-pic"
                    [src]="DownloadImage(9)"
                    id="photo"
                    alt="user avatar" width="50">
            </td>
        </ng-container>
```

now when i send the request it  send many request to server .

i have 4 item but it send for firstImage 4 time and for next 8 time .

whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ???

Comment: Where do you call the `DownloadImage` method?

Comment: @PrerakSola i edit the question . in `[src]`

Comment: As you are using a `for` loop, you can do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40799136/4350275
Calling a method in `src` is really a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I heard that methods can be called by Angular a lot of times. If you call the downloadImage inside the init method of the component, you could access this.image with a binding instead.

```
<img class="table-user-pic"
                    [src]="image"
                    id="photo"
                    alt="user avatar" width="50">
```

(But if you could access the images in the server through a url directly, instead of streams and blob, you could make more use of the existing features in the browsers instead. But this might not be possible in your case)

Comment: it is in table . i have for item

Comment: aha. But try the binding it might call the server less times. Things happens in loops. And you should avoid calling methods in the components from the html markup.

Comment: i need call the function . and i pass dynamic id

Comment: I would have preferred that every row data in the table had a property called ex: element.imageUrl when you get i from the server. The server could calculate the url before sending it. Then you could just bind that to the image: [src]="element.umageUrl". But that is not the case her I understand. Instead you could use rxjs to get all the images after you get the 'loop data'. The images could be set to another collection. [src]="images[index]". Its better to do the server calls in the init method.

Comment: i havent access to directly image access . it send me a file and i need to convert that for show image

Comment: In f12 you could look at the url that gets called when you call postService.downloadImage(id). Have you tryid hardcoding it in the src property? ex: theurl/tothe/imageFile/456

Comment: i try that . its not work

Comment: what happens if you copy the full link into the browsers urlfield? Can the browser show it? It might fail of security reasons also.